# Polymorphic I/O utility functions for Java 7 file I/O

Tags: java, clojure, io, java-7, clojure-contrib

Is there a library for I/O utility functions for Java 7 file I/O akin to clojure.java.io available in Clojure Contrib or elsewhere?

Specifically, I'm interested in the utilities which could provide a Clojure-friendly, coercive API that make using `java.nio.file.Paths`, `java.nio.file.Path` and `java.io.File` just work much like `clojure.java.io.file` and `clojure.java.io.as-file` does with respect to `java.io.File`. In fact I imagine that such a library would leverage and these functions, but make it easy to get at the additional path manipulation functionality provided by the `java.nio.file` package such as `relativize`, `subpath`, etc....

Comment: probably... but perhaps you could be more specific regarding what sort of IO utility functions you are trying to find?

Comment: how about this one: https://github.com/Raynes/fs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this one that I came across https://github.com/ToBeReplaced/nio.file